# Scroll to a specific DataList item in a UserControl

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datalist, datalistitem

I am working on an ASP.NET application where I have 3 user controls embedded in an aspx page which in turn uses a master page.

2 Usercontrols out of the 3 have a DataList. I would like to scroll to a specific / selected DataListItem in the usercontrol.

Also, I looked at this thread (http://forums.asp.net/t/1596201.aspx). But I don't think it will work in my case. And I have MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" in the aspx page - No luck still.

It would be really helpful, if someone could help me figure out a way to do this

The markup looks something like this

```
     <asp:DataList ID="dl" runat="server"
            SkinID="DataList" onitemcommand="dl_ItemCommand" 
            >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblIDTitle" runat="server" Text="ID: " />
                <asp:Label ID="dlLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'  />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select">Select</asp:LinkButton>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DisplayName") %>' />
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: we need to know how your markup looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is pretty simple. Here are the steps:

- In the user control containing the datalist, added this method..

  ```
   public void FocusControlOnPageLoad(string ClientID, System.Web.UI.Page page)
   {
       ClientScriptManager clientScript = this.Page.ClientScript;
       clientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"CtrlFocus",

                      @"<script> 

            function ScrollView()

            {
               var el = document.getElementById('" + ClientID + @"')
               if (el != null)
               {        
                  el.scrollIntoView();
                  el.focus();
               }
            }

            window.onload = ScrollView;

            </script>");

  }
  ```
- As you can see from the mark-up I had a linkbutton. So with the OnItemCommand, I called this function whenever the link button was clicked. Something like this;

  ```
  protected void dlCommitment_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
  {            
      if (e.CommandName == "Select")
      {  
          LinkButton link = LinkButton)dlCommitment.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex].FindControl("btnSelectCMTMT");
           FocusControlOnPageLoad(link.ClientID, this.Page);
      }
  }
  ```

And it worked like a charm. Thanks to a post that discussed about ScrollIntoView and a code project article about the method I have posted above. Since I'm on a rush, I'm not able to attach the links. Thanks to the ones who posted this information originially.

Answer (score 0):

easiest trick will be if u have any focusable html element like anchor or button in datalist, set tab index to it as zero, or use js to put focus on it.

Comment: @hungryMind.. I am quiet not sure how to do that. Can you give me an example based on the above markup?